# Using Set but Error 'Application-defined or object-defined error' shows up

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry the question is not so specified. I've tried to use `Set` to help me filling a quelity control table, but the error 10o4 show up. It seems correct for me and so I don't know how to correct it. So please take a look of it, and leave a comment if you've got some idea. Thank you!

```
Private Sub FillTarget(ByVal TargetSheet As String, ByVal DepositSheet As String, _
        ByVal TargetRow As Integer, ByVal TargetColumn As String, _
        ByVal DepositRow As Integer, ByVal DepositColumn As Integer)

Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim OpenedFile As String
Dim myObject As String

Dim MarkRow As Integer
MarkRow = 1
Dim myData As String
Dim EndSearch As Boolean

Dim TargetCell As Range
Dim TargetTag As Range
Dim TargetType As Range
Dim TargetZone As Range
Dim TargetTest As Range

Dim DepositTag As Range
Dim DepositZone As Range
Dim DepositResult As Range

For i = 3 To TargetRow
    With Worksheets(TargetSheet)
        myObject = .Cells(i, 15).Text + "_" + Worksheets(TargetSheet).Cells(i, 17).Text
        Set TargetCell = .Cells(i, TargetColumn) <==== Here comes the error
        Set TargetTag = .Cells(i, 15)
        Set TargetType = .Cells(i, 17)
        Set TargetZone = .Cells(i, 18)
        Set TargetTest = .Cells(i, 20)
    End With

    For j = MarkRow To DepositRow
        With Worksheets(DepositSheet)
            Set DepositTag = .Cells(j, 1)
            Set DepositZone = .Cells(j, 2)
        End With

        If InStr(DepositTag.Text, myObject) <> 0 Then
            OpenedFile = OpenedFile & DepositTag.Text & "|"

            If InStr(DepositZone.Text, TargetZone.Text + ":") <> 0 _
                Or InStr(TargetZone.Text, "/") <> 0 Then

                For k = 2 To DepositColumn
                    With Worksheets(DepositSheet)
                        Set DepositResult = .Cells(j, k)
                    End With

                    If InStr(DepositResult.Text, TargetTest.Text) <> 0 Then
                        MarkRow = j
                        myData = DepositResult.Text
                        'Split_monData
                        'Derniere_Colonne
                        TargetCell.Value = myData
                        EndSearch = True
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next k

            End If

        End If

        If EndSearch Then Exit For
    Next j

    EndSearch = False
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: just FYI, your code can be shortened a ton by placing your "Dim"s in one line.  Instead of `Dim range1 As Range` new line `Dim range2 As Range`, they all can be written as `Dim range1 As Range, range2 As Range`.  Important to note that you must always include the `As Range` (or whatever the object is), or that particular variable will be auto-declared as a Variant

Comment: To complete @RGA's comment, you should write `Option Explicit` above your `Sub` so you'll always have to declare your variables. Also, be careful when you declare `Dim i, j, k As Integer` only `k` is declared as integer, i and j will be as `Variant` you need to write `Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer`

Comment: Nice to meet you again @Rémi! And for the `Option Exolicit`, could you please explain a little bit? I don't know why and how to use it.

Comment: @Hiddenllyy You just need to write `Option Explicit` in the first line of your module. This way if you are using a variable that you forgot to declare when you run the macro it won't work. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `Cells()` is the value of the cell.  Pass it as a Range to define the Range object variable.

Everywhere where you have a Range variable equal to `.Cells(something)`, change it to `.Range(.Cells(something).Address)` and it should work as intended

Further, `TargetColumn` is declared as a string, rather than a numeric value.  If the string value is not of a column name (ie "A" or "B"), this will error.  Either pass the variable to a numeric value with Cdbl() CInt() or Clng(), or declare the variable with a numeric type from the start

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. I've changed `.Cells(i,j)` into `.Range(Cells(i,j).Address)`, but still i met the error 1004.

Comment: @Hiddenllyy I see now it could be related to "TargetColumn" which is passed in as a string. Is this string value an uppercase letter representing a specific column?

Comment: @RGA is right. `TargetColumn` is declared as String so if its values is supposed to be `1` you will get `"1"`. You need to declare it as a numerical variable (integer, Long, etc) or as a Range and add `.Column` right after.

Comment: @Hiddenllyy alternatively, you can just add Cint(TargetColumn) which will pass the value as an integer, although this is not always the smartest way to do this.  Declaring it numeric from the start would be the best